# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a login form that authenticates using postgresql I'm trying to check if users exists then redirect the client to the other page. The code is:

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  var Enteredusername = req.body.username;
  var Enteredpassword = req.body.password;

  pool.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = $1 AND password = $2", [Enteredusername, Enteredpassword], (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log('error in query', err);
    // need to check if user exists
    let user = (result.rows.length > 0) ? result.rows[0] : null;
    if (!user) {

      req.flash('notify', 'This is a test notification.')
      res.render('login', {
        messages: req.flash('Username or Password is incorrect !')
      });
      return res.redirect('/login')

    }
    res.redirect('/posts')

  });
});
```

And I got the error:

> _http_outgoing.js:470
>      throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Make the redirect conditional otherwise you will always redirect and then try to manipulate the response after it is finalized.

Comment: Did you mean to put your redirect within your query callback?

Comment: Your last edit, although rather small, dramatically changes the outcome of your program.  You are now redirecting from within your query callback.  Are you still having the issue?

Comment: @zero298 Yes, The issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's the async behavior of javascript `res.redirect('/posts')` is executed before `req.flash` and `res.render` you can hack it like this :

```
req.session.userId = Enteredusername;

if (!user) {

  req.flash('notify', 'This is a test notification.')
  res.render('login', {
    messages: req.flash('Username or Password is incorrect !')
  });

  return res.redirect('/login')

}else{
    return res.redirect('/posts')
}
```

Comment: it did not work for me. Is there a way to change the behavior as you said to synchronous for this part of code?

Comment: Try to delay your `res.redirect('/posts')` using a `setTimeout()` but is not a best practice if you want something clean do rewrite your code async/await based promises

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi I think you meant to write `return res.redirect('/login')` at the end of your `if`.

Comment: @HosseinA7 if you copied this answer, see my above comment to ensure there isn't a typo in your code

Comment: Yes Sorry it my bad it's was a Typo check now

Comment: @developing2020 Yeah I noticed, but it does not solve my problem